# what's error in my class definition?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i trying to take some code from a computation geometry book and i found this error 
need help!

```
class Point2D{
        ..
        ..
        some functions
        ..
        ..

        int classify(Point2D &p0, Point2D &p1) {
                Point2D p2 = *this;
                Point2D a = p1 - p0;
                Point2D b = p2 - p0;
                double sa = a.x * b.y - b.x * a.y;

                if (sa > 0.0) return LEFT;
                if (sa < 0.0) return RIGHT;
                if ((a.x * b.x < 0.0) || (a.y * b.y < 0.0)) return BEHIND;
                if (a.length() < b.length()) return BEYOHD;
                if (p0 == p2) return ORIGIN;
                if (p1 == p2) return DESTINATION;
                return BETWEEN;
        }

        int classify(Edge2D ed) {
                return Point2D::classify(ed.org, ed.dest);
        }


};

class Edge2D {
public:
        Point2D org;
        Point2D dest;

        ...bla bla bla

};
```

compiler errors:

```
syntax error: identifier 'Edge2D'
'ed': undeclared identifier
left of '.org' must have class/struct/union
left of 'dest' must have class/struct union
'Point2D::classify': no overloaded function takes 1 arguments
```

help ! :(

Comment: Class `Edge2D` must be seen before declaration of `Point2D`. How to solve this you can [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

Use forward declaration of `Edge2D` class before `Point2D` class as:

```
class Edge2D;
class Point2D{
    // your class members...
};
class Edge2D{
    // your class members..
};
```

Comment: if you implement both classes in the same file it will not work.
the compiler will show error : using undefined type of ......

but it works for me when i implemented -- the method of first class that uses the second class -- after the second class 
something like this 
class Edge2D;
class Point2D{
    int classify(Edge2D &e); // declared here but must be defined after class edge2D class
}
class edge2D{
    Point2D p1, p1;
}
int Point2D::classify(Edge2D &e){
    lab lab la;
}
this gonna work )

Comment: @MohamedKhaled my answer will also work. Did you checked my answer?